# Why did Cal encourage people to kill the changelings?

Tags: the-changeling

In *The Changeling*, the witch (?) Callisto encourages women whose babies have apparently been taken by fairies and replaced by changelings to kill the replacements and offers them aid in doing so. She also offers them shelter on her island after they have completed the deed.

Now, doing this naturally tends to put these women on the wrong side of the law, thus forcing them to live life in hiding or be imprisoned, and it means that they have to take their children to live this life, too. It also means leaving behind their families (save for their children) and particularly romantic partners.

Apparently, none of the women have ever recovered the babies that had apparently been taken by fairies, and Cal does not seem to be encouraging them to do so or providing much assistance in that regard. To cap it all off, their group has apparently been attacked at least once by a lethally angry spouse and has attracted the ire of a group of misogynistic Anonymous imitators who may be *literally* demonic.

Cal does say that killing the changelings provides some "closure," or "certainty," but that seems a very steep price to pay for all of the previous. Why, then, does Cal encourage people to kill the changelings?